# Images and Darkmode not switching

Tags: swift, xcode, ios13, ios-darkmode

In a couple of my apps, I have an image covering the view in the background.  In my asset catalog, my image has an Any, light and dark variation.  In iOS 13, when I launch the app, the correct light or dark mode image is displayed according to the mode set.  However, when I switch the mode while the app is running, the image does not change.  All other properties change (colors etc) for all controls, but not the image.
I have tried the following with a layoutIfNeeded() and/or layoutSubviews() inside the traitCollectiosnDidChange block:

```
 override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    guard let previousTraitCollection = previousTraitCollection else {return}
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            if previousTraitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: traitCollection) {
            print("Changed mode")
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.view.layoutSubviews()
        }
    }
}
```

and the Change mode is definitely triggered but the layout does not change.
Is there a way to make sure that the image also displays the correct one?

Comment: Interesting. How do you set the image? Is it working if you re-set the image in `traitCollectionDidChange`?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

OK.  To answer my own question.  I was applying .withHorizontallyFlippedOrientation() to my image and setting it in ViewDidLoad.  When I changed the trait color mode, this image was not getting change.
The solution was to to reset the image AND the flip property when the differentColorAppearance triggers.  Like this

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    guard let previousTraitCollection = previousTraitCollection else {return}
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        if previousTraitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: traitCollection) {
            image2.image = UIImage(named: "CourseImage")?.withHorizontallyFlippedOrientation()
    }
  }
}
```